# Invoking Future method in a loop

Tags: scala

Given the case class `Person` defined as:

```
case class Person ( first: String, middle: String, last: String )
```

And the case class `Band` that contains many `Person`s:

```
case class Band ( name: String, members: List[Person] )
```

What I need is to add the middle initial in Person for each member in the band, taking into account that the function `getMiddle` is actually a Future. This is my attempt:

```
case class Person ( first: String, middle: String, last: String )
case class Band ( name: String, members: List[Person] )

object TestFutures3 extends App {

  val p1 = Person ( "David", "", "Gahan" )
  val p2 = Person ( "Martin", "", "Gore" )
  val band = Band ( "Depeche Mode", List(p1,p2) )

  def getMiddle (name: String) = Future { 
    if (name == "Martin")
      "L"
    else
      "X"
  }

  val membersWithMiddle = band.members.map { 
              p => Person(p.first, getMiddle(p.first).map(_), p.last)
         }  

  println(membersWithMiddle)

  Thread.sleep(5000)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either await the future, and assign the middle directly:

```
val middle = Await.result(getMiddle(p.first), Duration.Inf)
val x: Person = Person(p.first, middle, p.last)
```

Or you can return a future person:

```
val x: Future[Person] = getMiddle(p.first).map(middle => Person(p.first, middle, p.last)
```

Comment: The future person option seems better, but how you integrate it in the code? how do you change `band.members.map { ` ?

Comment: band.members needs to be a `List[Future[Person]]`

Comment: sorry, I cannot change the case classes, it's legacy code

Comment: Then you'll have to await the future. It is the only way to force the unwrapping of a Future.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Future.traverse`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future$.html#traverse[A,B,M[X]%3C:TraversableOnce[X]](in:M[A])(fn:A=%3Escala.concurrent.Future[B])(implicitcbf:scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[M[A],B,M[B]],implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[M[B]]) :

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val setMiddleName: Person => Future[Person] =
  member => getMiddle(member.first).map(middle => member.copy(middle = middle))

val bandMembers: Future[List[Person]] =
  Future.traverse(band.members)(setMiddleName)

bandMembers.foreach(println)
// List(Person(David,X,Gahan), Person(Martin,L,Gore))
```

`Future.traverse` takes in this case a `List[Person]` and a `Person => Future[Person]` function (which will be executed for every `Person` - except if one of the `Future`s fails) and returns a `Future[List[Person]]`.

Comment: After you calculate `bandMember`, don't you have to wait before you print them?