# Passing in a Int value that comes from a Option Future

Tags: scala

I have a method I am struggling with that has a Option[Future[User]].

```
def insertEmployee(userOpt: Option[User], ...): Future[...] = {

  val userOptFut: Option[Future[User]] = userOpt.map { user => 
    userDao.insert(....) // returns a Future[User]
  }

  for {
    employee <- employeeDao.insert( Employee(..., ??, ......) )
  } yield ...

}
```

Now the issue I am having is that Employee case class takes an optional UserId value:

```
case class Employee(..., userId: Option[Int], ...)
```

***How do I pass the user.id value to the Employee case class if it is present?***

Comment: `user.id` present in what? `userOptFut`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invoking Future method in a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40901747/invoking-future-method-in-a-loop)

Answer (score 1):

You can do a small trick with the `Option[Future[Int]]`:

```scala
for {
  List(user) <- Future.sequence(userOptFut)
  employee   <- employeeDao.insert(Employee(..., user.id, ...))
}
```

Comment: If userOpt is None, I pass in None instead of user.id, in your example it won't do that.

Comment: That's what I said in the last part. The result will be a Failed future. This is the downside of using for comprehension here instead of pattern matching.

Comment: You should use `Future.sequence` to turn an `F[G[_]]` into a `G[F[_]]`

Comment: Agreed, fold is used for more complex reductions: for { x :: _ <- Future.sequence(userOptFut.toList) } :). I'll edit the post, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will need a little bit of logic to transform your types into the things you want:

```
val userOptFut: Option[Future[User]] = ???

// Convert the Option[Future[User]] to a Option[Future[Int]]
val maybeFutureID = userOptFut.map(_.map(_.id))

// Convert the Option[Future[Int]] to a Future[Option[Int]]
val futureOptionID = maybeFutureID match {
  case None => Future.successful(Option.empty[Int])
  case Some(futureID) => futureID.map(id => Some(id))
}

for {

  // Wait for Future[Option[Int]]
  maybeID <- futureOptionID

  // Insert employee
  employee <- employeeDao.insert(Employee(..., maybeID, ...))
} yield ...
```